# How to make a local copy of a html page be run as if it was the online version?

Tags: javascript, html, proxy

I'm a bit new to programming and I've been having a problem trying to open an html document as if it was opened through the page itself. I'm thinking I need to create a proxy for my browser whenever it opens the file, but I'm not certain.

The reason I need this is because when the file is stored locally it conflicts with how it runs and leaves somethings.

EDIT: Solved, my site uses AJAX, making it impossible for what I want.

Comment: What do you mean by "run", is that more than "open"? In what format did you store it?

Comment: to "run" an html document you open the file with a browser

Comment: Sorry, I used the wrong word. I meant that if I open a local file it is different than the web based one. The document is stored as an html, however it has a javascript component which is what doesn't work.

Comment: This is almost impossible to do for many modern Ajax-powered sites. What is your use case, what do you need to achieve?

Comment: I need to manage a way to open a local html file, while not opening as a localhost.

Comment: Do you know if it's css and scripts point to relative or absolute paths? (`<script type ="text/javascript" src="/scripts/file.js">`is relative where `<script type ="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/scripts/file.js">`is absolute..)

Comment: You can get tools to make local copies of websites, no need to make a proxy.

Comment: And if it uses Ajax, listen to @Pekka웃

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing websites that you did not author for later offline use can be challenging. This may or may not work depending on the scripts being used. Your best bet is to check the file for absolute paths, and change them to relative if possible.

```
i.e: <img src="http://google.com/img/test.jpg"> to <img src="img/test.jpg">
```

The same goes for all javascript and CSS.

This is assuming there isn't any 2 way communication with javascript after the page loads. If it uses any AJAX or polling you are basically screwed.

Any reason you need this offline? Is it just data, or data plus UI interaction?

If only data, you may be able to save it in another format for later viewing. 
If you need the graphical interaction, or you need it to update once online again you may be out of luck.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I'll take a look at it and see if there are any non-absolute paths. What I need is just data, that gets pulled from the server however it only pulls some and not all of it.

Comment: After checking again, it seems that it was using AJAX. Thanks for the help, sorry about the convoluted question.